# Tykewriter Font from Scholastic

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, font-identification

I have been searching for the font "Tykewriter," often used by Scholastic Publishers. I've been in contact with the creator of the font, Josh Korda, who sadly no longer has a copy of the font.
Scholastic has not been helpful in providing information about the font either. Would anyone on this forum know where or how I could obtain a copy of the Tykewriter font?

Comment: If the author can't answer it, I think it's probably a long shot that we can. Then again, you never know...

Comment: Hi Travis, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

The question got me curious so off on a google hunt I went...

Found this thread archived from Typophile: http://web.archive.org/web/20141114141104/http://typophile.com/node/37437

The last comment states:

> The font was created by a guy named Josh Korda and was based on my own handwriting. We created it as designers for Scholastic Publishing in the early 1990's.

Based on that, it sounds like it's an in-house typeface created by Scholastic for their own use, so the source would be them.

Another thread on MyFonts that states the same: http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/case/28372/